# Getting error while putting RegularExpression

Tags: c#, regex, string

What I am looking for is to find `GPA` in **String array**. This is code but I am getting error when I put regular expression.

```
for (int l = 0; l < resplitted.Length; l++)
{
     Regex regex = new Regex(^[0]|[0-3]\.(\d?\d?)|[4].[0]$); //error here
     Match match = regex.Match(x[i]);
     if (match.Success)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("GPA is :"+match.Value);
     }
}
```

Comment: `Regex r = new Regex(@"^[0]|[0-3]\.(\d?\d?)|[4].[0]$");`

Comment: Same problem again: What is correct Regex for Percentage(with decimal 2 digit decimal point precision)?  `Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}+%\$");`

Comment: You seem to have an accepted answer. Is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the `Regular Expression` in double quotes `""` with `@` symbol

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[0]|[0-3]\.(\d?\d?)|[4].[0]$");
```

Note : a string  prefixed with `@`  will disable the escape sequences starting with `\`

or

you can use double `\\` slash without using `@` symbol

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[0]|[0-3]\\.(\\d?\\d?)|[4].[0]$");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, because it should be a string.

try this:

```
 @"^[0]|[0-3]\.(\d?\d?)|[4].[0]$"
```